# Calculate widest distance between two lines

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to calculate the mean distance as well as the widest distance between two lines. I know how to find the minimum distance using st_distance() function, but I'm not sure how to find the other two metrics. The red lines are what I believe I would need to measure to find the mean and widest distances between the two lines. 
[image]

Attached is some example data.

```
pts1<- data.frame(
  x= c(-103.485342, -103.482808),
  y = c(31.348758, 31.376947))
) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts1)<- "+init=epsg:2257"

pts2<- data.frame(
  x= c(-103.492822, -103.484231),
  y = c(31.348181, 31.377191))
) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts2)<- "+init=epsg:2257"

a <- pts1 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()
b<- pts2 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()

min_dist<-st_distance(a,b,by_element = T)
```

See second example below. From the image i calculate ~300 meters from the perpendicular line which cross both lines at its maximum.

[image]

```
pts1 <- data.frame(x = c(-103.485342, -103.482808),
                   y = c(31.348758, 31.376947)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts1) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

pts1<- st_transform(pts1,"+init=epsg:2257")


pts2 <- data.frame(x = c(-103.492812, -103.484231),
                   y = c(31.318181, 31.377991)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))


st_crs(pts2) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

pts2<- st_transform(pts2,"+init=epsg:2257")

a <- pts1 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()
b <- pts2 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()

st_distance(pts1, pts2, by_element = T)
```

Comment: It seems like you are meaning lien segments, not lines. Can you clearly define "mean" and "max" distance between lines? Should they be perpendiculars from one line to another (from mid and end points)? If so, from which line to which?

Comment: To make it simpler, I would like to find the maximum width distance, assuming a perpendicular line is drawn between the left line. For example, the last line in the image would be the widest distance between the two lines assuming a perpendicular line was drawn.

Comment: Assuming a perpendicular line, `st_bbox(st_union(pts1,pts2))` would give you `xmax` and `xmin` that is the maximum distance between lines

Comment: is there a way to compute the bounding box based off the shorter line to the longer line? Basically, i want the max distance of the perpendicular line based off of the shorter line to the longer line. Apologies for not communicating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an insight, maybe this is not a complete answer you would imagine.

As lines are made of points, if you just make two slightly changes, you can have not only min distance, but also max distance by doing the same thing you did with the lines, but with the points from which the lines are comprised.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 6.2.1

pts1 <- data.frame(x = c(-103.485342, -103.482808),
                  y = c(31.348758, 31.376947)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts1) <- "+init=epsg:2257"

pts2 <- data.frame(x = c(-103.492822, -103.484231),
                   y = c(31.348181, 31.377191)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

st_crs(pts2)<- "+init=epsg:2257"

a <- pts1 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()
b <- pts2 %>% st_coordinates() %>% st_linestring()

st_distance(pts1, pts2, by_element = T)
#> Units: [US_survey_foot]
#> [1] 0.007502222 0.001443768
```

For having the mean distance, I am not sure if this is what you want, but I think you can obtain the centroid of both lines and then process `st_distance`.

```r
ca <- st_centroid(a)
cb <- st_centroid(b)

st_distance(ca, cb, by_element = T)
#> [1] 0.004454613
```

**EDIT: my last try based on comment**

I think you can maybe have what you're trying to have if you find the longest line (b in your example), than process and find the longest distance between the points of the shorter line and the longest line itself:

(I also made some changes to your original code to make it works)

```r
library(sf)

pts1 <- data.frame(x = c(-103.485342, -103.482808),
                   y = c(31.348758, 31.376947)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y")) %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  st_transform(2257)

pts2 <- data.frame(x = c(-103.492812, -103.484231),
                   y = c(31.318181, 31.377991)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y")) %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  st_transform(2257)

a <- pts1 %>% 
  st_union(.) %>% 
  st_cast(to = "LINESTRING")

b <- pts2 %>% 
  st_union(.) %>% 
  st_cast(to = "LINESTRING")

longest <- ifelse(test = st_length(a) > st_length(b),
                  yes = quote(a),
                  no = quote(b))

max(st_distance(pts1, eval(longest)))
#> 955.7374 [US_survey_foot]
```

Comment: I think this answer is really close, but I'm getting a wrong answer when one line is quite a bit longer than the other, like in the example below. Appreciate your help though! I've added a second example to the question showing a longer line. What I'd like is the maximum distance where the perpendicular line touches both line.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer if I can't figure out how to do it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you always have absolute straight lines in your study or they eventually can "make curves"?

Comment: They will always be straight lines.

Comment: My last try, @jsimpsno. My head is blowing up!

Comment: Ahh! that's it!! You have no idea how long i've tried to find a solution! Thank you so much.

Comment: if it helps, `sfheaders::sf_linestring( pts )` should ease the sf-generating code.